# GDI+ anmation equivalence to requestAnimationFrame

Tags: winapi, animation, gdi+, gdi, requestanimationframe

I am new to Win32 programming. With my prior knowledge in browser javascrip animation. I knew it is important to use **requestAnimationFrame**. But I havn't found similar functions in **GDI+.** Although I shouldn't expect win32 to have all the similar browser apis, but I would like to know, am I looking in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're looking in the wrong direction.  GDI+ isn't designed for animation.  Use [Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370990.aspx) instead, or one of the higher-level wrappers like [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx).